# JavaScript - detect Native keyboard finished loading or closed event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, angularjs-directive

We are writing wizard based multi-form , and creating Helium based flow on mobile devices.

most of our widgets are Angular based that contain text title and  's element (using the native keyboard)

Helium Event means that we scrolling the page to show the focused element is in top highest position (highest position after the Flow Header)

the scrolling is based on the Window size.

```
|-----Header-----|
|    [ title ]   |
|    [ input ]   |
|                |
|----Keyboard----|
|  1  2  3  4  5 |
|  6  7  8  9  0 |
|----------------|
```

- The user click on the **input element directly** the scroll calculation is
  based on the current Window size because we cannot detect when the native   keyboard is open.
- Focusing on the input directly causing the native keyboard to change the Window size and the now the the page scrolling is wrong.
- Also Can we detect keyboard closed event and only then we will scroll to the next element?

Comment: There's more than one thing called "Helium" out there, mind elaborating?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your scenario correctly you could try something like this.

Basically you determine if the currently focused element is an input element... and if it is, presume the keyboard is showing (otherwise entering data would be difficult)

```
var currElem = document.activeElement;
if($(currElem).is('textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="number"]')){
    //a textural input element has focus, thus the keyboard is
    //very likely showing :-)
}
```

It isn't foolproof, but theoretically I think this should work.

Comment: Hi . we will override the basic input widget but right now the problem is that if the input element position is overlap the keyboard position then after the keyboard open -> window re-size event -> will trigger another scroll -> now the widget in the wrong place.

Comment: What do you think about listening to the touch Start event and then find the relevant position after the page header. then propagate the input focus event. in this case the element is not overlap the keyboard and there will not be another scroll event

Comment: Any chance you can post a screenshot?